# sending multiple parameters to another function in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a function that adds some functionality to the link_to function in rails. What I'd like it to do is simply to add a class to it. What I have so far:

```
#application_helper.rb
def button_link(*args)
    link_to(*args.push(class: 'btn'))
end
```

Problem is that if I now add another class to the button_link function it doesn't work.

Example:

```
<td class='button'>
    <%= button_link "Show", category_path(item), class: "btn-primary" %>
</td>
```

I get the following error: `wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)`. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: This means you gave 4 parameters to the `link_to` helper (expecting 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

link_to has 4 method signatures.. This is the one used most often.

Below we check to see if a class was already sent in -- and because of how HTML classes work, we want to have multiple classes, which are space-separated values.

```
  def button_link(body, url, html_options={})
    html_options[:class] ||= ""
    html_options[:class] << " btn"
    link_to body, url, html_options
  end
```

The other method signatures can be viewed http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your helper method to this, trying to maintain the link_to form:

```
def button_link(name, url_options, html_options = {})
  if html_options.has_key?(:class)
    css_options = html_options.fetch(:class)
    css_options << ' current'

    html_options.merge!( { :class => css_options } )
  else
    html_options.merge!( { :class => ' btn' } )
  end

  link_to(name, url_options, html_options)
end
```